# How to limit the number of cores in function plsr from the R package pls?

Tags: r

I am using:

```
model <- plsr(y ~ x, method = "simpls", data = train_data, validation = "CV", segments = 5)
```

On Linux, this uses all cores of my machine.
While this is fast, sometimes I need to limit the number
of cores used by a single calculation.

Calling

```
pls.options(parallel = 4)
```

before the call to plsr doesn't change anything
to the fact.

Thanks!

Comment: did you try calling it with `makeCluster()`? `pls.options(parallel = makeCluster(4, type = "PSOCK"))` It's from `parallel` package

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it does not work. The machine is still using all cores. I even suspect it is overloaded given what htop is showing.

Comment: :/ if got another idea that does not fix your core problem. But maybe it helps you. You can change the niceness of the process. So every other process is more relevant. This is quite useful, since your pc is working normaly and only free calculation power is used. You can try [checking the doc](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/tools/html/psnice.html) or try `psnice(pid = 8)`. Can't test how it works at the moment. Also note that it could be problematic with `parallel`. But i'm using nice on python if i run ML tools for hours and still want to work. Maybe worth a try